# XSSI attacks with source maps

Tags: security, xss, source-maps

The [Source Map Proposal](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1U1RGAehQwRypUTovF1KRlpiOFze0b-_2gc6fAH0KY0k/edit?hl=en_US&pli=1&pli=1) mentions possible [XSSI](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.co.at/2011/05/website-security-for-webmasters.html) attacks that make the source maps "available to attackers".

Can someone explain how that is a security problem? Aren't "attackers" able to download the source maps directly?

Answer (score 0):

That would be a problem if the source maps contain information based on the requestor's cookie credentials (just like other XSS attacks).

Comment: Yep, I thought of that. But that seems very unlikely to me.